# C - Passing va_list to a sentinel-terminated function - need wrapper for execlp()

Tags: c, wrapper, variadic-functions, variadic, ellipsis

I am trying to write a wrapper for execlp().
Why doesn't this work? Is it the sentinel?

```
int vExeclp(const char *file, const char *arg, va_list argptr)
{
  int returnValue = 0;

  returnValue = execlp(file, arg, argptr, NULL);

  // error handling if returnValue == -1

  return(returnValue);
}


int Execlp(const char *file, const char *arg, ...)
{
    int returnValue = 0;
    va_list argptr;

    va_start(argptr, arg);

    returnValue = vExeclp(file, arg, argptr);

    va_end(argptr);

    return(returnValue);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: No process is overloaded when calling    Execlp("./nameOfProcess", ./nameOfProcess", arg1, arg2);

Answer (score 3):

`execlp` is a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D) so [you can not create a wrapper](http://c-faq.com/varargs/handoff.html) for it. You will need to call `execvp` passing an of array strings created by iterating over your va_list.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a `va_list` to a variadic function; it simply does not work that way. The only thing you can do is read the argument list into an array yourself until you get to the null terminator, then pass the array to `execvp`.